# pig latin - create multiple row output from single line input

Tags: hadoop, apache-pig

I had input data like below:

> Row1|2014-04-04 18:46:18|37.52|-84.34|30870|580.372 ms, 759.065 ms,
>   695.879 ms
>
> Row2|2014-04-04 18:47:18|37.68|-84.34|31127|619.341 ms, 725.121 ms,
>   696.790 ms

How can I make into multiple rows as below:

> Row1|2014-04-04 18:46:18|37.52|-84.34|30870|580.372 ms
>
> Row1|2014-04-04 18:46:18|37.52|-84.34|30870|759.065 ms
>
> Row1|2014-04-04 18:46:18|37.52|-84.34|30870|695.879 ms
>
> Row2|2014-04-04 18:47:18|37.68|-84.34|31127|619.341 ms
>
> Row2|2014-04-04 18:47:18|37.68|-84.34|31127|725.121 ms
>
> Row2|2014-04-04 18:47:18|37.68|-84.34|31127|696.790 ms

thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

You can use `FLATTEN`. E.g.,

```
a = load 'test.txt' using PigStorage('|') as (c1: chararray, c2: chararray, c3: double, c4: double, c5: long, c6: chararray);
b = foreach a generate c1, c2, c3, c4, c5, STRSPLIT(c6, ', ', 3) as c6;
c = foreach b generate c1, c2, c3, c4, c5, FLATTEN(c6) as (c6: chararray, c7: chararray, c8: chararray);
dump c;
```